# Where is the best place to ask questions and report bugs about SE sites?

Tags: discussion

When I am using a Stack Exchange site and I come across a bug or an issue that I want a really good answer on, or immediate attention, I always feel like running back to this site (meta.stackoverflow).

http://meta.stackexchange.com is the place I feel is most logical for entering into discussion about how things should work, asking for a new feature or reporting a bug. I find questions there are few and far between and the community is lacking compared to what is here at MSO.

Where is the best place for me to request bug fixes / feature requests and general question about SE sites?

Do others agree that the MSO community is the current birthplace for most feature requests and bug reports and that this may cause people like myself to come from other sites to ask question about SE sites here? (is this good/bad/appropriate)

Obviously with a large number of Stack Exchange staff and Jeff using this site regularly, I am more inclined to jump on here just to get noticed (I know this sounds bad, but I just want to point it out). Especially if its for a new feature request that I want.

Do moderators from SE Beta sites have a path to raise certain community concerns or feature requests from within their own communities. e.g. A great feature request for a certain community which may have benefit for those in other SE sites?

Comment: MSE no longer exists (except as a redirect to this site) so this question can be safely closed and deleted now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MSO FAQ:

> If your question is about:
>
> Stack Overflow
>   Stack Exchange Area 51
>   **The core Stack Exchange engine** that powers all Stack Exchange websites

Basically, if it's a general issue that applies to most sites, then bring it here. Otherwise, your local meta site is the right place (and they are monitored by the SOISI staff for issues).

Comment: So does that mean if I add a feature request to a SE 2.0 site in meta it will be viewed and status updated e.g. by-design etc.??

Comment: @xiao Yes. They watch and monitor all Meta sites.

Answer (score 2):

waiwai is spot on. But just to explain about Meta Stack Exchange: it's for questions about the Stack Exchange 1.0 sites. They're not making any more SE 1.0 sites, but Jeff has said that the team will basically going to keep MSE open for the existing ones until they're all closed.