# Where/how do I report a bug on this site?

Tags: support, bug-reports

I can't search because a Captcha keeps failing. There's no one to tell. Who has responsibility for this? Where can I click to report the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you really have a problem, you should report it on either your site meta (for a site-specific problem) or this site, [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) (for a network-wide problem). In either case, ask it as a question, use the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag to indicate that you think it is a bug, and add relevant tags to further indicate the scope of the question.

See [Where is the best place to ask questions and report bugs about SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69191/where-is-the-best-place-to-ask-questions-and-report-bugs-about-se-sites?rq=1) for more details.